# Managing max and min in an input[number] when entering text directly

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to create a component input with the type number where you can setup a max and a min with Angular

Here is my code :
This is the HTML code which called the component :

```
<app-input-number [(value)]="inputMinMaxValueNumber" [min]="min" [max]="max"></app-input-number>
```

This is the HTML code for the component :

```
<input class="gh-input" type="number" [max]="max" [min]="min" [name]="name"  
[readonly]="readonly" [disabled]="disabled" [ngClass]="disabled ? 'disabled' : ''" [value]="value" />
```

And the typescript for the component :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-number',
  templateUrl: './input-number.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-number.component.scss']
})
export class InputNumberComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() name: String;
  @Input() readonly: Boolean;
  @Input() disabled: Boolean;
  @Input() max: number;
  @Input() min: number;
  currentValue: number;

  @Output()
  valueChange = new EventEmitter<number>();

  @Input()
  get value() {
    return this.currentValue;
  }

  set value(val) {
    if (val > this.max) {
      this.currentValue = this.max;
    } else if (val < this.min) {
      this.currentValue = this.min;
    } else {
      this.currentValue = val;
    }

    this.valueChange.emit(this.currentValue);
  }

  constructor(private translateService: TranslateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

The problem is that when i'm entering a value manually by entering a value higher then the max, it'll work the first time but then it won't limit the value anymore (it works for the min tho)

Any help would be welcomed.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "it won't limit the value anymore"? Can you describe a sequence of actions that does not work?

Comment: For exemple, for a min of 0 and a max of 5, if i enter 8, the value displayed will be 5. But if i enter 8 again the value will be 58

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work because you cannot two-way bind with `value` property to `input` element. Use `ngModel` instead.

BUT anyway, using `ngModel`, or in general two-way binding, is your worst option. Use FormGroups with custom validators instead.

Comment: Exactly what i needed.
Using a FormControl solved the problem